# Syntax regex to extract the source of an image

Tags: php, regex

Ahoy there!

I can't "guess" witch syntax should I use to be able to extract the source of an image but simply the web address not the `src=` neither the quotes?

Here is my piece of code:

```
function get_all_images_src() {
    $content = get_the_content();
    preg_match_all('|src="(.*?)"|i', $content, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
    foreach($matches as $path) {
        echo $path[0];
    }
}
```

When I use it I got this printed:

```
src="http://project.bechade.fr/wp-content/uploads/2009/09/mer-300x225.jpg"
```

And I wish to get only this:

```
http://project.bechade.fr/wp-content/uploads/2009/09/mer-300x225.jpg
```

Any idea?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I don't know PHP, but I'd suggest trying PREG_PATTERN_ORDER, and maybe $path[1].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks [Ithcy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/59461/ithcy) for his right answer.
I guess I've been too long to respond because he deleted it, I just don't know where his answer's gone...

So here is the one I've received by mail:

> '|src="(.*?)"|i' makes no sense as a
>   regex. try '|src="([^"]+)"|i' instead.
>   (Which still isn't the most robust
>   solution but is better than what
>   you've got.)
>
> Also, what everyone else said. You
>   want $path[1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/59461/ithcy), NOT $path[0]. You're
>   already extracting all the src
>   attributes into $matches[]. That has
>   nothing to do with $path[0]. If you're
>   not getting all of the src attributes
>   in the text, there is a problem
>   somewhere else in your code.
>
> One more thing - you should use a real
>   HTML parser for this, because img tags
>   are not the only tags with src
>   attributes. If you're using this code
>   on raw HTML source, it's going to
>   match not just  but 
>   tags, etc.
>
> — ithcy

I did everything he told me to do including using a HTML parser from Bart (2nd answer).

It works like a charm ! Thank you mate...

Answer (score 5):

Not exactly an answer to your question, but when parsing html, consider using a proper html parser:

```
foreach($html->find('img') as $element) {
  echo $element->src . '<br />';
}
```

See: http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Really interesting mate ! Thanks for sharing... Makes things pretty easier

Answer (score 3):

`$path[1]` instead of `$path[0]`

Comment: I'm using '$path[0]' because I want to display all the src images, I just get the first one with '$path[1]'

Answer (score 0):

```
echo $path[1];
```

$path[0] is the full string matched. $path[1] is the first grouping.

Answer (score 0):

You could explode the string using " as a delimeter and then the second item in the array you get would be the right string:

$array = explode('"',$full_src);

$bit_you_want = $array[1];

Reworking your original function, it would be:

```
function get_all_images_src() {    
$content = get_the_content();    
preg_match_all('|src="(.*?)"|i', $content, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);    
foreach($matches as $path) {   
$src = explode('"', $path);     
echo $src[1];    
}
}
```